# libz.so is missing when trying to build

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cmake, ubuntu-16.04, ninja

I am building a project using cmake 3.5.1 and ninja on Ubuntu 16.04 server.

When I try to build I get an error about finding a zlib dependency..

```
ninja: error: '/usr/lib/libz.so' needed by 'MyProject', missing and no known rule to make it.
```

I have checked and confirmed I have zlib1g-dev package installed.

I assume the following line in cmake is what is looking for the libz.so

```
target_link_libraries(MyProject ${ZLIB_LIBRARIES})
```

The following line is present in the CMakeLists.txt

```
find_package(ZLIB REQUIRED)
```

Comment: Does the solution suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/931284/641475) apply to your situation? Also, what version of CMake are you using? You might do better by linking to `ZLIB::ZLIB` imported target, instead of `${ZLIB_LIBRARIES}`.